# how to delete data array on jsonb postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13

how to update array data in `jsonb` column on database postgresql?

for example on table `table1` i have column `attribute` that have value like this:

| id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"task_customs": ["a", "b", "c"]}] |
| 2 | [{"task_customs": ["d", "e", "f"]}] |

for example if i want to delete `b` from id `1`, so it will be like this on `attribute` column

| id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"task_customs": ["a", "c"]}] |
| 2 | [{"task_customs": ["d", "e", "f"]}] |

already do some research but didn't get what i need..

Comment: im using postgre 13.0

Comment: Will the outer array always contain exactly one element? What if you have multiple elements with the key `task_customs` in the outer array?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there's no possibility to have duplicate key, but the data may can have more than one key for example `[{"task_customs": ["a", "c"], "another_key": "another_value"}]`..

Comment: Hi Jazuly, I've edited the answer depending on the last need on your comment

Answer (score 2):

try this :

(a) Delete 'b' acccording to its position in the array :

```
UPDATE table1
   SET attribute = attribute #- array['0', 'task_customs', '1'] :: text[]
 WHERE id = 1
```

(b) Delete 'b' without knowing its position in the array :

```
WITH list AS
( SELECT id, to_jsonb(array[jsonb_build_object('task_customs', jsonb_agg(i.item ORDER BY item_id))]) AS new_attribute
    FROM table1
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(attribute#>'{0,task_customs}') WITH ORDINALITY AS i(item,item_id)
   WHERE id = 1
     AND i.item <> 'b'
  GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE table1 AS t
   SET attribute = l.new_attribute
  FROM list AS l
 WHERE t.id = l.id
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d9a1d5e1c7e3fdfe718482cc77fbd138).

Comment: its not working when i have more then one object, for example [{"task_customs": ["a", "c"], "another_key": "another_value"}] it will update to [{"task_customs": ["a", "c"]}]..

Comment: There is no magic function for deleting part of a json data in pgsql, so you have to break down and then rebuild your json data, and this solution highly depends on your json data struture. My answer is based on your initial question and set of example.

Comment: yup, thanks for the answer, i solved this based on your and make some modification..

Answer (score 1):

One option is to start splitting the JSONB value by using `jsonb_to_recordset` such as

```sql
UPDATE table1 AS t
   SET attribute = 
      (
        SELECT json_build_array(
                            jsonb_build_object('task_customs',task_customs::JSONB - 'b')
                          ) 
          FROM table1,
       LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(attribute) AS (task_customs TEXT)
         WHERE id = t.id
      ) 
 WHERE id = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a81d6e900224a27c4cda90d1409da82)</kbd>

**Edit :** If you need more elements as expressed within the comment then you can rather prefer using

```sql
UPDATE table1 AS t
   SET attribute = 
      (
        SELECT jsonb_agg(
                    jsonb_build_object(key,je.value::JSONB - 'b')
               ) 
          FROM table1,
       LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(attribute) AS atr,
       LATERAL jsonb_each_text(atr::JSONB) AS je
         WHERE id = t.id
      ) 
 WHERE id = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=541172534bbe4d82078896e79f2d7da2)</kbd>

Comment: its not working when i have more then one object, for example `[{"task_customs": ["a", "c"], "another_key": "another_value"}]` it will update to `[{"task_customs": ["a", "c"]}]`..

Answer (score 0):

i solve this issue by combining both answer from Edouard and Barbaros

this is my final query

```
UPDATE table1 AS t
   SET attribute = 
      jsonb_set(
        attribute,
        '{0,task_customs}',
        (
          SELECT task_customs::JSONB - 'b'
          FROM table1
          CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_to_recordset(attribute) AS (task_customs TEXT)
          WHERE id = t.id
        ) 
      )
WHERE id = 1
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=676f630fcdb3e758225dfd83278155d4)